# Why viminfo setting doesn't work in VIM

Tags: vim, vimrc

I set the [viminfo](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/doc/options.txt?r=840c3cadb8428aaa62103d34715f71563da40d7e#7518) in [my .vimrc](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/Linux/Vim74_Vundle/.vimrc) for making startup faster. However the setting doesn't work.

The setting is:

```
set viminfo=%,\"100,'10,/50,:100,h,f0,n~/.vim/cache/.viminfo
```

When I tried to `echo &viminfo`, the value was just the same as the older (maybe default) one:

[image: viminfo]

I using vim 7.4 which was compiled and installed by myself, here is the version information:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 17 2013 16:56:58)
Included patches: 1-131
```

And this is the source code installation configures:

```
./configure --enable-gui=gnome2 --enable-cscope --enable-multibyte --enable-xim --enable-fontset --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-python3interp=yes --enable-rubyinterp=yes --enable-python3interp=yes --prefix=/home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74 --with-compiledby=Marslo > vim-build.log
```

What's wrong with my setting? What should I do to make the setting work?

Comment: Why do you use `"100` instead of `<100`? Could it be possible that you still have an old `~/.viminfo`?

Comment: Yeah! That's great idea!! I've changed the `\"` to `<`. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's easily explained. You have

```
:set nocompatible
```

**after** `:set viminfo`. The former is a special, important option, which affects others; from `:help 'compatible'`:

> This is a special kind of option, because when it's set or reset, other options are also changed as a side effect.

The solution is easy: Move it to the start of your `~/.vimrc`, or drop it altogether, as `nocompatible` is implied by having a `.vimrc` file.

Comment: Thanks! I've `set nocompatible` in my vimrc file (because I'm using vundle). However, the `set viminfo=xxx` should add after `set nocompativle`.

Comment: Well, there some problem with my Gvim (in win7). viminfo still cannot be set. What should I do?

Comment: Okay, I fix that.